# Kendo UI Dropdownlist complex object

Tags: json, kendo-ui

How to bind json data below to Kendo UI Dropdownlist?

```
{
    _count: 4200,
    result: [ {id:1,text:"fff"}, {id:2,text:"fff"}]
}
```

Comment: I meet this issue because , I need to bind a big data to this dropdownlist, and write demo by Kendo UI document suggest, but I cannot bind this data to it .

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code, I can't tell you where you are going wrong; this works and described in the demo for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
 
var data = {
  _count: 4200,
  result: [ {id:1,text:"fff"}, {id:2,text:"fff"}]
};

$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
   dataTextField: "text",
   dataValueField: "id",
   dataSource: data.result
});

});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```